# Cakephp Containing deeper associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having a Blog that User can Like and Comment on them. For the Blog View action, I will list out all the comments for this blog entry. Til now I am able to list out all the comment but I want to show the Username as well, unfortunately I only got the User_id in the Comment object. What should I do? I already tried out recursive = 2.

[image: Here is a trace of the variable:]

It is giving an error Model "Rmcomment" is not associated with model "User" [APP/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 342] while only the last level of the query doesn't work

Comment: If you tried something, please show what you've tried in a reproducible fashion, as `recursive = 2` should definitely include that association. That being said: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442675/containable-and-deep-associated-data**

Comment: Post the query that you're currently using to generate the `blog` array. You should be using `containable` instead of `recursive = 2` as its extremely ineffecient

Comment: my action is 

public function view($id = null) { 
 $this->Blog->recursive = 2;
 
 if (!$this->Blog->exists($id)) {
  throw new NotFoundException(__d('croogo', 'Invalid %s', __d('rm', 'blog')));
 } 

 $options = array('conditions' => array('Blog.' . $this->Blog->primaryKey => $id));  
 $this->set('blog', $this->Blog->find('first', $options));
}

Answer (score 0):

Ello, mate. Try to use the *joins* on your find query.

```
$this->Rmcomment->find('all', array(
 'joins' => array(
      array(
      'table' => {{ya users table name}},
      'alias' => 'User',
      'type' => 'LEFT',
      'conditions' => array('User.id = Rmcomment.user_id')
   ),
  'fields' => array(
    'Rmcomment.something', 
    'Rmcomment.somethingelse', 
    'User.name' //Here comes your name from users table using the user_id from comments
    ),
  'group' => 'Rmcomment.id'
  )
 )
);
```

It should return:

```
array(
    array(
        'Rmcomment' => array(
            '!fields from Rmcomment!'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            '!fields from User!'
        )
    ),
    array(
         'Rmcomment' => array(
            '!fields from Rmcomment!'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            '!fields from User!'
        )
     ).........
 );
```